# Automatic google account login Selenium

Tags: python

**I need help solving this problem, I tried everything on the Internet, but it does not help
I'm trying to sign in to a google account with python selenium
I use pyautogui library but it doesn't work**
[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x8E2.jpg)

Thes my code

```
from logging import error
```

from sys import executable
import time
import requests

from selenium import webdriver
import geckodriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

if **name** == "**main**":

```
from selenium_stealth import stealth
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
stealth(browser,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )

# get login page
browser.get(
    "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=ar&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fhl%3Dar&ec=GAlA8wE&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession")

while True:
        # print(browser.page_source)
         pyautogui.write("my number")  
         pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: *I tried everything on the Internet?* **What exactly did you tried?** *I am trying to sign in to a google account with selenium* **What exactly are you trying? Where is the code?** *I use pyautogui but it doesn't work* **How it does not work? What are the errors or bugs?**

Comment: It gives me Couldn't sign you in every time I try to login from chrome driver

Comment: @Naderelsayed - Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

This [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en) page states that sign in via browsers that "Use automation testing frameworks" is being disabled for the following [security reasons](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/04/better-protection-against-man-in-middle.html) and Google advices to do "Sign in with Google" using [browser-based OAuth 2.0 authentication service](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app).

As some websites, like [stackoverflow.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com) allow you to sign in to their services using "Sign in with Google" it must happen via Google OAuth 2.0 authentication. This implicates that doing so you are also indirectly signing in to your Google account and therefore you can use all the Google services.

So you can fully automatically sign in to your Google account, e.g. by using a Python script, by performing these actions in your code:

1. Open a new browser window that is controlled by selenium webdriver
2. In the same window load the StackOverflow login page (or any other site that uses "Sign in with Google")
3. Choose for "Log in with Google"
4. Provide your Google account credentials and login to StackOverflow
5. Load the Google mailbox by opening https://mail.google.com/ or https://www.gmail.com/

This way you land down in your Gmail mailbox without performing any manual actions.

**Please remember to add some 5s delays between different actions as doing it too quickly or too frequently can be recognized by StackOverflow as malicious automated actions and you can get blocked and you will need to make the manual `I'm not a robot` verification**

Other hacks that I know of to solve this:

Do the 2 step-verification for your Google account on the browser you intend to use for selenium — just once for the IP-address you’re using. This might work because the blockage is dependent on the IP address. Once verified, the IP address should be deemed safe by Google.

If that does not work, use Firefox browser instead of Google Chrome. The logic behind this is that fact that the chrome driver is coded by Google, and they are able to recognize if this is a bot or not. With Firefox however, there are better chances that Google does not recognize it as bot. You will need to show the Google site that you are not a robot. You can do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import geckodriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(
    '/Users/<user name>/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxx.default-release')

profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
profile.update_preferences()
desired = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,
                           desired_capabilities=desired)
```

This [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/255587/how-to-find-your-firefox-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20locations%20are%3A,%2FFirefox%2FProfiles%2Fxxxxxxxx.) can help you find the Firefox profile path on your system.

Comment: I have added the code now

Comment: I did that but it gives me this error
https://j.top4top.io/p_2414ovl8c1.png

Comment: thes my code [link](https://f.top4top.io/p_2414zzfb51.png)